# How to compare two dataframe rows by rank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe (this is only a part of it):

```
    replicate  N_offspring group  survival  rank offs  rank sur
27   H-CC-81          339   CCC        87          7        13
28   H-CC-82          285   CCC        89         16        12
29   H-CC-83          261   CCC        82         18        19
30   H-CC-84          312   CCC       108         12         5
31   H-CC-85          205   CCC        84         26        15
32   H-CC-86          153   CCC        59         28        27
```

I want to do a test on the 'n_offspring' and 'survival' rows based on each of their separate ranks(rank offs,rank sur).
for example, 'N_offspring' that is 'rank off'= 20 will go against 'survival that is 'rank sur'=20

Answer (score 0):

I used `sort.values` two groups and then compare the rows that I needed:

```
def spearman_group_test(group):
    group_value = the_dict[group]
    rank_by_off = group_value.sort_values(by=['rank offspring'])
    rank_by_sur = group_value.sort_values(by=['rank survival'])
    s_test = stats.spearmanr(rank_by_off['N_offspring'],rank_by_sur['survival'])
    print(group, s_test)

for keys in the_dict:
    spearman_group_test(keys)
```